# How to read pdf bookmark using apache tika?

Tags: java, apache-tika

I'm using apache tika library for reading pdf content. Dose the same library allow to read pdf bookmarks as well?

Comment: http://tika.apache.org/1.3/ (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-1035).

Comment: Proper punctuation - use a question mark on questions

Answer (score 2):

> Does the same library allow to read pdf bookmarks as well?

I think the answer is Yes.

- I found a Tika bug report (fixed) about text extraction from PDF bookmarks not working.
- Tika uses the Apache PDFBox library for reading PDF files, and the website for that library says it handles PDF bookmarks.

And ...

- *"PDF: Text from bookmarks is now extracted (TIKA-1035)."* from the Tika 1.3 release notes.